# Is there a way to spawn in travel tickets?

Tags: tomodachi-life

Is there a way to get Travel Tickets for free? This is an alternative for an Instant Marrage cheat and is much more useful, so it is worth it asking for a cheat to get infinite/have a way to spawn in travel tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way to get travel tickets is to help your Miis. This would be easy if it weren't for the abundance of cough medicine that you'll get!

Comment: Then I wish Action Replay wouldn't break your 3DS.